# SVN Load to older repository, but SVN Clients can't commit newer files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin, svn-administraton

So our SVN server died overnight and the most recent dump was performed and copied off the server the day before.

Got a new SVN server up and going and loaded all the repositry backups from the last successfull dump. However there were commits made to the old server after the dump was performed. Testing the new server, I see that TortoiseSVN identifies that the local client files are being the lastest and there are no commits needed, however I know the server is outdated and those most recent commits need to be committed again.

I want to do this as efficiently as possible. Is there a way to increase the server repository number somehow and force the client machines to perform an update? ( like run a cleanup command within Tortoise and it will then identify which files need to be re-committed ). There are a number of developers all using/accessing different repositories that we have setup for each client/project.

Thanks for any advice/help. I am brand new to SVN administration and this is the first time I had to perform a restore.

Derek

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is the following:

- find a working copy containing the latest changes
- make a fresh checkout from  the new repo to a new working copy location
- use WinMerge or some other diff tool to make it so that the fresh (but obsolete) working copy contains exactly the same files as the old (but up to date) working copy
- commit the changes from the fresh working copy to the new repo
- ask all the developers to delete their working copy and checkout from the new repo

Comment: Thanks JB. Yeah if we have to go down that route, that was my original thought. The only issue is ensuring that others do this process correctly and I would prefer not having to do this for each user myself. I would prefer to do some sort of automated process somehow from the server level and have each user do a refresh or SVN clean or something but I am not even sure if that could be possible at this point. Thanks for the help!